# UIScrollView with contentsize set can't scroll beyond frame boundary

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I Feel like I'm missing something super obvious here.

I have a UIScrollView in a storyboard, with a outlet to the view controller.

I programatically add a series of views, and set the content size of the scroll view.

Even though I've set the scrollview's contentsize height to a very high value, I can't scroll beyond the views bounds.

I'm printing the content size and frame size after setting it. As well as the contentoffset.y when the scrollview scrolls.

Here is an example of the console output:

```
2013-09-24 21:54:34.531 [Redacted] scrollView frame size: 320.000000,460.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:34.531 [Redacted] scrollView content size: 0.000000,10000.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.259 [Redacted] scroll to: 6.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.275 [Redacted] scroll to: 17.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.291 [Redacted] scroll to: 29.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.308 [Redacted] scroll to: 41.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.325 [Redacted] scroll to: 52.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.341 [Redacted] scroll to: 65.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.358 [Redacted] scroll to: 74.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.375 [Redacted] scroll to: 84.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.392 [Redacted] scroll to: 90.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.408 [Redacted] scroll to: 95.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.425 [Redacted] scroll to: 100.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.441 [Redacted] scroll to: 103.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.459 [Redacted] scroll to: 107.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.475 [Redacted] scroll to: 110.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.492 [Redacted] scroll to: 114.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.509 [Redacted] scroll to: 118.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.525 [Redacted] scroll to: 122.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.542 [Redacted] scroll to: 126.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.558 [Redacted] scroll to: 130.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.575 [Redacted] scroll to: 134.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.592 [Redacted] scroll to: 141.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.609 [Redacted] scroll to: 147.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.625 [Redacted] scroll to: 152.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.642 [Redacted] scroll to: 156.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.659 [Redacted] scroll to: 159.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.676 [Redacted] scroll to: 160.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:36.776 [Redacted] scroll to: 161.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.010 [Redacted] scroll to: 162.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.026 [Redacted] scroll to: 168.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.043 [Redacted] scroll to: 179.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.060 [Redacted] scroll to: 195.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.077 [Redacted] scroll to: 207.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.097 [Redacted] scroll to: 209.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.112 [Redacted] scroll to: 219.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.129 [Redacted] scroll to: 223.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.145 [Redacted] scroll to: 222.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.162 [Redacted] scroll to: 218.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.179 [Redacted] scroll to: 212.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.195 [Redacted] scroll to: 204.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.212 [Redacted] scroll to: 195.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.229 [Redacted] scroll to: 186.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.245 [Redacted] scroll to: 177.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.262 [Redacted] scroll to: 168.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.279 [Redacted] scroll to: 160.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.296 [Redacted] scroll to: 152.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.312 [Redacted] scroll to: 145.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.329 [Redacted] scroll to: 138.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.346 [Redacted] scroll to: 133.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.362 [Redacted] scroll to: 127.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.379 [Redacted] scroll to: 122.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.396 [Redacted] scroll to: 118.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.412 [Redacted] scroll to: 114.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.429 [Redacted] scroll to: 111.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.445 [Redacted] scroll to: 108.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.462 [Redacted] scroll to: 105.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.479 [Redacted] scroll to: 103.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.496 [Redacted] scroll to: 101.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.512 [Redacted] scroll to: 99.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.529 [Redacted] scroll to: 98.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.545 [Redacted] scroll to: 96.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.562 [Redacted] scroll to: 95.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.579 [Redacted] scroll to: 94.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.595 [Redacted] scroll to: 93.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.629 [Redacted] scroll to: 92.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.645 [Redacted] scroll to: 91.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.695 [Redacted] scroll to: 90.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.745 [Redacted] scroll to: 89.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:37.862 [Redacted] scroll to: 88.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.381 [Redacted] scroll to: 89.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.397 [Redacted] scroll to: 108.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.414 [Redacted] scroll to: 127.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.431 [Redacted] scroll to: 150.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.448 [Redacted] scroll to: 164.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.464 [Redacted] scroll to: 182.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.481 [Redacted] scroll to: 195.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.499 [Redacted] scroll to: 213.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.516 [Redacted] scroll to: 222.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.533 [Redacted] scroll to: 224.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.550 [Redacted] scroll to: 222.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.566 [Redacted] scroll to: 217.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.583 [Redacted] scroll to: 209.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.599 [Redacted] scroll to: 201.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.616 [Redacted] scroll to: 192.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.633 [Redacted] scroll to: 183.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.650 [Redacted] scroll to: 174.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.666 [Redacted] scroll to: 166.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.683 [Redacted] scroll to: 157.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.699 [Redacted] scroll to: 150.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.716 [Redacted] scroll to: 143.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.733 [Redacted] scroll to: 137.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.749 [Redacted] scroll to: 131.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.766 [Redacted] scroll to: 126.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.783 [Redacted] scroll to: 121.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.799 [Redacted] scroll to: 117.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.816 [Redacted] scroll to: 113.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.833 [Redacted] scroll to: 110.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.849 [Redacted] scroll to: 107.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.866 [Redacted] scroll to: 105.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.883 [Redacted] scroll to: 102.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.900 [Redacted] scroll to: 100.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.916 [Redacted] scroll to: 99.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.933 [Redacted] scroll to: 97.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.950 [Redacted] scroll to: 96.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.966 [Redacted] scroll to: 95.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:38.983 [Redacted] scroll to: 94.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:39.000 [Redacted] scroll to: 93.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:39.016 [Redacted] scroll to: 92.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:39.049 [Redacted] scroll to: 91.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:39.083 [Redacted] scroll to: 90.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:39.150 [Redacted] scroll to: 89.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:39.267 [Redacted] scroll to: 88.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.145 [Redacted] scroll to: 91.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.162 [Redacted] scroll to: 97.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.178 [Redacted] scroll to: 103.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.195 [Redacted] scroll to: 109.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.212 [Redacted] scroll to: 115.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.229 [Redacted] scroll to: 120.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.245 [Redacted] scroll to: 124.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.262 [Redacted] scroll to: 127.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.279 [Redacted] scroll to: 130.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.296 [Redacted] scroll to: 131.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.312 [Redacted] scroll to: 133.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.329 [Redacted] scroll to: 135.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.345 [Redacted] scroll to: 136.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.374 [Redacted] scroll to: 137.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.664 [Redacted] scroll to: 138.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.681 [Redacted] scroll to: 139.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.697 [Redacted] scroll to: 143.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.714 [Redacted] scroll to: 149.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.731 [Redacted] scroll to: 155.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.748 [Redacted] scroll to: 161.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.764 [Redacted] scroll to: 166.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.781 [Redacted] scroll to: 169.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.798 [Redacted] scroll to: 172.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.814 [Redacted] scroll to: 174.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.831 [Redacted] scroll to: 177.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.848 [Redacted] scroll to: 178.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.865 [Redacted] scroll to: 180.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.887 [Redacted] scroll to: 181.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.914 [Redacted] scroll to: 183.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.948 [Redacted] scroll to: 184.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.981 [Redacted] scroll to: 186.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:43.998 [Redacted] scroll to: 187.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.015 [Redacted] scroll to: 188.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.031 [Redacted] scroll to: 189.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.048 [Redacted] scroll to: 190.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.065 [Redacted] scroll to: 191.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.082 [Redacted] scroll to: 192.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.116 [Redacted] scroll to: 194.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.149 [Redacted] scroll to: 195.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.182 [Redacted] scroll to: 196.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.216 [Redacted] scroll to: 197.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.266 [Redacted] scroll to: 198.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.283 [Redacted] scroll to: 199.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.299 [Redacted] scroll to: 200.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.316 [Redacted] scroll to: 202.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.349 [Redacted] scroll to: 203.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.366 [Redacted] scroll to: 204.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.449 [Redacted] scroll to: 205.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.500 [Redacted] scroll to: 206.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.601 [Redacted] scroll to: 207.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.932 [Redacted] scroll to: 189.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.949 [Redacted] scroll to: 174.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.966 [Redacted] scroll to: 161.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.982 [Redacted] scroll to: 151.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:44.999 [Redacted] scroll to: 141.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.016 [Redacted] scroll to: 133.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.032 [Redacted] scroll to: 126.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.049 [Redacted] scroll to: 121.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.066 [Redacted] scroll to: 116.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.082 [Redacted] scroll to: 112.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.099 [Redacted] scroll to: 108.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.116 [Redacted] scroll to: 105.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.133 [Redacted] scroll to: 102.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.149 [Redacted] scroll to: 100.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.166 [Redacted] scroll to: 98.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.183 [Redacted] scroll to: 97.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.200 [Redacted] scroll to: 96.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.216 [Redacted] scroll to: 94.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.233 [Redacted] scroll to: 93.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.266 [Redacted] scroll to: 92.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.283 [Redacted] scroll to: 91.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.316 [Redacted] scroll to: 90.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.366 [Redacted] scroll to: 89.000000
2013-09-24 21:54:45.483 [Redacted] scroll to: 88.000000
```

As you can see, I can't scroll beyond 200 odd.

I'm not new to iOS and have worked with scroll views before so I feel like I must be missing something really obvious.

Any help greatly appreciated, have a tight deadline!

EDIT: Added code:

```
checkboxes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
{
    // Just indented scope for tidyness, no functional meaning
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Oil Level Checked"
                                                     atY:190]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Coolant Level Checked"
                                                         atY:240]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Tyre pressures & tread dept checked"
                                                         atY:290]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Warning beacon & horn operating"
                                                         atY:340]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Lights & indicators working & clean"
                                                         atY:390]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Screen was & wipers operational"
                                                         atY:440]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Mirrors undamaged & clean"
                                                         atY:490]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Road Tax & MOD discs present & valid"
                                                         atY:540]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"PPE in vechile"
                                                         atY:590]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Fire Extinguisher & First Aid kit present"
                                                         atY:640]];
    [checkboxes addObject:[self createCheckboxWithLabel:@"Wheel nuts checked with torque wrench"
                                                         atY:690]];
}
for(WpCheckboxWithLabelView *checkbox in checkboxes){
    [scrollView addSubview: checkbox];
}

// Set content size of scrollview
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 10000);
scrollView.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"scrollView frame size: %f,%f", scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"scrollView content size: %f,%f", scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto layout was the cause of the issue here. I'm not exactly sure of the details, but [Apple's documentation describes the behavioural differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) of `UIScrollView`s when paired with autolayout.

I believe my issue was due to the scrollview being defined in the storyboard and subviews added programatically. To solve the issue I created the `UIScrollView` programatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing in one my views and it works fine for me. I attached the code:

```
CGSize s = CGSizeMake(mainDetailView.frame.size.width,
                      view1.frame.size.height + MARGIN +
                      view2.frame.size.height + MARGIN +
                      view3.frame.size.height + MARGIN +
                      view4.frame.size.height + MARGIN + 10000);

[mainDetailView setContentSize:s];

mainDetailView.clipsToBounds = NO;
mainDetailView.pagingEnabled = NO;
```

The Margin is a constant that I defined to be 20.

I can scroll beyond the limit of the views.

Maybe you can post your code and will be easier to help you.

Comment: I've added the code to the OP. I just create a series of custom views. They go beyond the scrollviews frame so I set content size pretty big, but I still can't scroll outside of frame. (as seen in console output in OP.)